# Flutter "RangeError (index): Invalid value" StreamBuilder

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm getting the following error

```
The following RangeError was thrown building StreamBuilder<InsightsModel>(dirty, state:
I/flutter (14582): _StreamBuilderBaseState<InsightsModel, AsyncSnapshot<InsightsModel>>#364a0):
I/flutter (14582): RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in inclusive range 0..3: -1
```

I can't figure out causing and or how to fix it

It's coming from

The relevant error-causing widget was:
I/flutter (14582):   StreamBuilder

Here is the code for that widget

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: Center(
            child: StreamBuilder(
                stream: widget.allInsights,
                builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<InsightsModel> snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.hasData) {
                    if (insights == null || insights.isEmpty) {
                      snapshot.data.insights.forEach((element) {
                        if (prefs.getInt(
                                'swiped_insight_${element.id.toString()}') ==
                            null) {
                          insights.add(element);
                        }
                      });
                    }
                    return Stack(
                      alignment: AlignmentDirectional.center,
                      children: buildCardsList(context),
                    );
                  } else {
                    return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                  }
                }),
          )),
    );
  }
```

and here is the code for `InsightsModel`

```
class InsightsModel {
  List<Insight> _insights = [];

  InsightsModel.fromJson(List<dynamic> json) {
    print('_insights');
    print(_insights);
    for (int i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
      _insights.add(Insight.fromJson(json[i]));
    }
  }

  List<Insight> get insights => _insights;
  List<Insight> getInsightsByLimit(int limit) {
    List<Insight> list = [];
    for (int x = 0; x < limit && x < _insights.length; x++) {
      list.add(_insights[x]);
    }
    return list;
  }
}
```

Comment: iu think that you wana do  if (   snapshot.data.insights == null ||    snapshot.data.insights.isEmpty)  not  if (insights == null || insights.isEmpty)

Comment: No that is not it, it was working fine it happens when I swipe on the cards a lot so it can't be that

Comment: yes because you tried to foreach insights even data not yet loaded so add  if (snapshot.data != null ) 
                    if (insights == null || insights.isEmpty) { ......

Comment: That is not it I think I fixed testing now

Answer (score 1):

So I finally found out was causing the issue I have the following `buildCardsList`

My app is like tinder where you have cards and swipe

This is the list widget, Basically **insights** was negtive at some point just need to add `if (insights.length - _nrCardsMax > 0)`

```
List<Widget> buildCardsList(BuildContext context) {
    // List<Company> lastCompanies = companies.sublist(0, 5);
    int _nrCardsMax = 5;
    List<Widget> cards = [];

    double initialBottom = 15.0;
    double backCardPosition = initialBottom + (_nrCardsMax - 1) * 10 + 10;
    double backCardWidth = -10.0;
    print(insights.length);

    if (insights.length - _nrCardsMax > 0) {
      for (int i = insights.length - _nrCardsMax; i < insights.length; i++) {
        bool _isLastCard = i == insights.length - 1;
        if (!_isLastCard) {
          backCardPosition -= 10;
          backCardWidth += 10;
        }
        cards.add(swipeableCard(
          _isLastCard,
          insights[i],
          _isLastCard ? bottom.value : backCardPosition,
          _isLastCard ? right.value : 0.0,
          0.0,
          _isLastCard ? backCardWidth + 10 : backCardWidth,
          _isLastCard ? rotate.value : 0.0,
          _isLastCard ? rotate.value < -10 ? 0.1 : 0.0 : 0,
          context,
          dismissInsight,
          flag,
          saveInsight,
          saveContactedContact,
          swipeRight,
          swipeLeft,
        ));
      }
    }
    return cards;
  }

  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
}
```